# No line drawn at mouseClick

Tags: java, swing

I have the following java programm:

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.io.*; 
  import javax.swing.*;

  public class Lapex extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
JPanel p = new JPanel();

Lapex(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    p.addMouseListener(this);
    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    f.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.show(true);
}


public void paint(Graphics g){
     paintComponents(g);
     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 100);
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
     System.out.println("AAAA");
     repaint();
}


}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Lapex();

}
}
```

Clicking the mouse, at the console is displayied "AAAAA", but draws no line.(I deleted the other mouse event)
How to modify ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the super method and use paintComponent.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: K Sorry, nothing happens

Comment: @EbticBobo What did you do?

Comment: K I simply replaced function paint(Graphics g) with function PaintComponent(Graphics g)

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note:

Your class extends `JPanel`, but then you create another `JPanel` inside the class that you actually add to the frame.  Add the instance of your class instead.

Override paintComponent instead of paint.

Use a call to invokeLater to start your program on the EDT. See [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html/) for more info.

Override getPreferredSize rather than call setPreferredSize.

Here is a complete example that toggles the line on/off when the mouse button is clicked:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lapex extends JPanel {

  boolean drawLine = false;

  Lapex(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
        drawLine = !drawLine;
        repaint();
      }
    });

    f.add(this);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(drawLine) {
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 100);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(600, 600);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        new Lapex();
      }});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No!, don't override `paint()` leave this up to Swing itself. All you should do is override `paintComponent()`.